# Calling ASP.NET MVC Action Methods from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have sample code like this:

```
 <div class="cart">
      <a onclick="addToCart('@Model.productId');" class="button"><span>Add to Cart</span></a>
 </div>
 <div class="wishlist">
      <a onclick="addToWishList('@Model.productId');">Add to Wish List</a>
 </div>
 <div class="compare">
      <a onclick="addToCompare('@Model.productId');">Add to Compare</a>
 </div>
```

How can I write JavaScript code to call the controller action method?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use jQuery ajax:

```
function AddToCart(id)
{
   $.ajax({
      url: 'urlToController',
      data: { id: id }
   }).done(function() {
      alert('Added'); 
   });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: There is a syntax error with the example above, as there should be a comma after data: { id: id }, but unfortunately it is deemed too trivial an edit for me to fix.

Comment: @Sterno I queued it up for a peer review. Thanks for leaving your post; it sped up my troubleshooting process.

Comment: What should I type in by **url**, the complete url, or just the action & controller?

Comment: The complete URL.

Answer (score 35):

> Simply call your **Action Method** by using **Javascript** as shown below:

```
var id = model.Id; //if you want to pass an Id parameter
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")/' + id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately (unless I'm way off here), this will require that you have the JavaScript WITHIN the .cshtml file. Personally, I definitely prefer my js in its own file.

Comment: This is a brillant solution. I always use JS inside all my .cshtml files because it is a good practice to include in it.

Comment: @MuratYildiz; Can I set Post or Get ?

Comment: @dellos I only used for GET, but both should be ok.

Comment: I had to remove the forward slash to make this work:  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' + id;

Answer (score 15):

You are calling the addToCart method and passing the product id. Now you may use jQuery ajax to pass that data to your server side action method.d

jQuery post is the short version of jQuery ajax.

```
function addToCart(id)
{
  $.post('@Url.Action("Add","Cart")',{id:id } function(data) {
    //do whatever with the result.
  });
}
```

If you want more options like success callbacks and error handling, use jQuery ajax,

```
function addToCart(id)
{
  $.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Add","Cart")',
  data: { id: id },
  success: function(data){
    //call is successfully completed and we got result in data
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                  //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error  
                  alert(xhr.responseText);

                }    
  });
}
```

When making ajax calls, I strongly recommend using the Html helper method such as `Url.Action` to generate the path to your action methods.

This will work if your code is in a razor view because Url.Action will be executed by razor at server side and that c# expression will be replaced with the correct relative path. But if you are using your jQuery code in your external js file, You may consider the approach mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168).

Answer (score 11):

If you want to call an action from your JavaScript, one way is to embed your JavaScript code, inside your view (`.cshtml` file for example), and then, use Razor, to create a URL of that action:

```
$(function(){
    $('#sampleDiv').click(function(){
        /*
         While this code is JavaScript, but because it's embedded inside
         a cshtml file, we can use Razor, and create the URL of the action

         Don't forget to add '' around the url because it has to become a     
         valid string in the final webpage
        */

        var url = '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")';
    });
});
```

Comment: ANy suggestion for using this kind of code in .js file?

Answer (score 11):

If you do not need much customization and seek for simpleness, you can do it with built-in way - [AjaxExtensions.ActionLink method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493106.aspx).

```
<div class="cart">
      @Ajax.ActionLink("Add To Cart", "AddToCart", new { productId = Model.productId }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" });
</div>
```

That MSDN link is must-read for all the possible overloads of this method and parameters of [AjaxOptions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx). Actually, you can use confirmation, change http method, set OnSuccess and OnFailure clients scripts and so on

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add this when you are using same controller to redirect

```
var url = "YourActionName?parameterName=" + parameterValue;
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: You can use a different controller also, `var url = "YourController/YourActionName?parameterName=" + parameterValue; window.location.href = url;`

Answer (score 5):

```
Javascript Function

function AddToCart(id) {
 $.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ControllerName")',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
   data: { 'id': id },
   success: function (results) {
        alert(results)
   },
   error: function () {
    alert('Error occured');
   }
   });
   }

Controller Method to call

[HttpGet]
  public JsonResult AddToCart(string id)
  {
    string newId = id;
     return Json(newId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your `element` with

`value="@model.productId"`

and

`onclick= addToWishList(this.value);`

Answer (score 1):

I am using this way, and worked perfectly:

```
//call controller funcntion from js
function insertDB(username,phone,email,code,filename) {
    var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
    //Iterating through each files selected in fileInput
    formdata.append("username", username);
    formdata.append("phone", phone);
    formdata.append("email", email);
    formdata.append("code", code);
    formdata.append("filename", filename);

    //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Home/InsertToDB');//controller/action
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
           //if success
        }
    }
}
```

in Controller:

```
public void InsertToDB(string username, string phone, string email, string code, string filename)
{
    //this.resumeRepository.Entity.Create(
    //    new Resume
    //    {
            
    //    }
    //    );
    var resume_results = Request.Form.Keys;
    resume_results.Add("");
}
```

you can find the keys (`Request.Form.Keys`), or use it directly from parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a **`<a>`** link in your view.

```
<a hidden asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy" id="link"></a>
```

then in you javascript code use this:

```
location.href = document.getElementById('link').href;
```