# C# function call in MVC using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, function, model-view-controller

I'm creating an API in MVC using C# for the back end of the API, and the standard HTML and JavaScript for the front end. My question is how do I reference the functions that I made in C# by using JavaScript in the front end?

I am new to HTML and JavaScript, so any help or references at all would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The word you need to know is [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

Comment: Investigate calling Web API services with jQuery/javascript

Comment: Thank you everyone, I shall begin investigation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling ASP.NET MVC Action Methods from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952953/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using jQuery Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MyController/MyAction",
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ param: myParameter }),
        success: function (result) {

        },
        failure: function (error) {
        }
    });
```

C#

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(string param)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect reference along with what DontVoteMeDown said. Thank you very much!