# Trying to call action method from jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to both MVC and JQuery, but this should not really be that difficult. When I call the function, nothing happens. I put an alert box in the function, and I can see that the function is called.

I found this, but it did not help me:
[Calling ASP.NET MVC Action Methods from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952953/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript)

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function oKButtonPressed(){    
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("MessageToPatient", "StartScreen")"
        });
    };
</script>
```

`MessageToPatient` is the name of the action method. `StartScreen` is the name of the controller.

Can you see something obvious I'm missing? Otherwise, it might be something with my MVC code.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your controller action to see if the action actually gets called.

Comment: By the way, you're not passing any data with your ajax post.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in it, and the action method is called.

Comment: Hmm, I mean all I want to do is call the action method, without any data passed.

Comment: Then, why does it have to be a post call?

Comment: And, if the action method is called, then what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to this. Anyway, I changed it to "GET" with the same result. I also removed the whole line, same thing.

Comment: The View that is supposed to be shown is not

Comment: But, you don't even need to use jQuery if it's GET request. And, you say the action is called. Then, what's the problem?

Comment: Hmm, ok, but I saw that in every answer when I googled it. I just wanted to call an action method. Anyway, this is my action method:
public ViewResult MessageToPatient()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: Can you post your action method too?

Comment: If I type in the URL in the browser, the view is generated

Comment: You can't return a View when using ajax. I'd suggest that you read a little bit more about Ajax, asp.net MVC, and jquery before starting to code.

Comment: Also check the positions where single quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Getting/posting to an action using jQuery.Ajax.

You can return data to this jQuery, but an MVC view will not be rendered as if it was just a normal request. You have to process the returned data in some way.

See this for example: http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html?m=1

Comment: Ok, thanks. Well if you were to just call an action method that renders a view with a button click, how would you do it?

Comment: Try googling a beginner's MVC tutorial, it'd be quicker than asking q's on here.