# Call controller without "clicking" in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to call a controller without clicking on a link?

By this I mean, without using `@Html.ActionLink` for example, something automatic that's call after a condition.

Thanks in advance !

Edit :

There is some code :

```
if (IsPost)
{
    if (!Request["idInterventions"].IsEmpty())
    {
                    string[] AllStrings = Request["idInterventions"].Split(',');
                    List<int> list = new List<int>();
                    foreach (string item in AllStrings)
                    {
                        int value = int.Parse(item);
                        list.Add(value);
                    }
                    Model.toFacture(list);
                    isDone = true;
                    //Need to call a controller method here 
    }
}
```

So my code is triggered after a POST.

Comment: Do you mean you want to call it from JavaScript? or Hardcode the Link in your HTML file?

Comment: _When_ do you want an HTTP request to be issued? Upon page load? Every N seconds? When the user interacts with some element? Keyword here is JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling ASP.NET MVC Action Methods from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952953/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript)

Comment: I added some infos to be more clear sorry

Comment: So you want to call another controller method from within a controller method? You do that like you call any other method. But you shouldn't; extract the logic out of the controller into a separate class, and call that class method from both places.

Comment: No this piece of code is in my view in fact ("maybe not a good idead but I'm new with asp.net,c#,etc...) so I want to know how to call it from my view

Comment: The code you've provided appears to be in a Controller - if that code is in the view, then it's probably in the wrong place.  Either way, this can be done as previously advised by extracting the "need to call method" into a "utility" class and calling it from both locations.

Comment: From your view, you can call any controller **action** using @Html.Partial.  In your example code, it doesn't look like you're not calling an "action", but just another "method".  Your controllers should only have public actions (that return `HtmlResult` or derivatives) and not general methods - these should be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Razor, you can use

```
Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "SomeArea", someParameter = Model.SomeParameterValue });
```

This renders the view returned by the action directly.

In controllers, you can use

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

This will result in a HTTP 302 Found redirect.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for ! I think I already tried to use it but now it's magically working thanks !