# use a javascript function to call a razor page asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Based on [Calling ASP.NET MVC Action Methods from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952953/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript) I've attempted to update a `cookie` message using `ASP.NET Core` by :

1. replacing `href` by `window.location.href` and
2. specifying `ActionName` + `ControllerName`.
3. I've also tried `window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")`

*[Problem]* : When clicking on the link, `1-3` redirect to https://www.cookiesandyou.com/, instead of https://localhost/ControllerName/ActionName . Please see below a sample code:

```
    window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    ....
},
"showLink": true,
"content": {
    "message": "test ",
    "window.location.href": "Dat?Home",
    "allow": "Allow"
}
```

});

Any idea would highly be appreciated.

*N.B: Using `ASP.NET`, this tasks was trivial since `href` was simply pointing to `/Dat`.*

Best

Comment: @URL.Action should work but you need to make sure that the action and controller exist for the helper method to generate the link

Comment: @Canolyb1: they do exist, as I've tested ```href: Home/Dat```. Problem was when clicking 2x on the same link, URL was point to ```Home\Home\Dat```, hence an exception. So I have to resort to solution posted which was strangely pointing  https://www.cookiesandyou.com/

Comment: to be a bit more accurate: href": "Home/Dat" points to the right url. However, ```window.location.href: Home/Dat``` points to cookiesandyou.com for unknown reasons. Unfortunately href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller") does not work and wonder whether a solution involving href could exist

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, using:

`"href: '/Home/Dat',"`

solves my issues : No automatic pointing to [cookiesandyou.com](https://cookiesandyou.com), and clicking `n` times to the link did not point to `Home\...\Dat`, thus yielding errors owing to the insertion of `/`.

Best.